# Passing Angular HttpClient Exception in Data Service back to Observers

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to implement a few good patterns in my application.  I've got a "Data Service" for sharing server side data with my components as below.

```
export class DataService {
private caseSource = new BehaviorSubject<ICase>(null);

currentCase = this.caseSource.asObservable();

constructor(private ccWebService: CCWebService) {
this.currentCase.subscribe(data => {
  if (data == null) {
    const currentId = localStorage.getItem('currentId');

    if (currentId) {
      this.loadCase(parseInt(currentId));
    }
  }
})
  }

  private changeCase(case: ICase) {
this.caseSource.next(case)
  }

  loadCase(Id: number) {
localStorage.setItem('currentId', Id.toString());
this.ccWebService.getCase(Id).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.caseSource.next(data);
  },
  error => {
    this.caseSource.next(error);
  });
}
```

My components then subscribe to the currentCase as below:

```
export class ViewComponent implements OnInit {

  case$: Observable<ICase>;
  loading: boolean = true;
  error: string = '';

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private ccWebService: ccWebService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
this.case$ = this.dataService.currentCase;
this.case$.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.loading = data == null;
  },
  error => {
    this.error = error;
    this.loading = false;
  });

  }
```

I also have an error interceptor as below:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService){}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                    // auto logout if 401 response returned from api
                    this.authenticationService.logout();
                    location.reload(true);
                }

                let errorMessage = '';
                if (err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                  // client-side error
                  errorMessage = `Client Error: ${err.error.message}`;
                } else {
                  // server-side error
                  errorMessage = `Server Error Code: ${err.status}\nError: ${err.error}\nMessage: ${err.message || err.statusText}`;
                }
                window.alert(errorMessage);

//                    const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
                return throwError(errorMessage);
    }))
}
}
```

Everything works fine apart from that my observers never receive the error, instead of the error function being called they always get the data function called instead.  I can't work out how to get the error data from the data service to the observers, via the error function.

Answer (score 0):

**HttpErrorResponse:**
The HttpClient captures the errors and wraps it in the generic HttpErrorResponse, before passing it to the catchError The error property of the HttpErrorResponse contains the underlying error object. It also provides additional context about the state of HTTP layer when the error occurred.

The errors falls into two categories. The back end server may generate the error and send the error response. Or the client side code may fail to generate the request and throw the error (ErrorEvent objects).

please visit [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-http-error-handling/) for a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think my question is more about how to I pass it back to the observers via the Behaviour Subject